# Is there a way to use a password submit tasks through the spark/hadoop client?

Tags: apache-spark, security, kerberos

The client program is insecure and requires authentication and auditing. Is there a way for clients to successfully submit tasks after configuring their accounts and passwords.
I understand the relevant knowledge of kerberos. The client can access the server by keytab file, but distributing files to the client is not very convenient.

I hope to replace the kertab file with a password. Can I implement it through kerberos? or there are other ways.
I need some technical guidance and keywords, and then I search for keywords to complete my needs
Thanks

Comment: Kerberos can integrate with LDAP for username/password, but that doesn't change that a keytab or JKS files are necessary

Comment: Is there any other way to implement it besides kerberos, as my software is brand new and any implementation method is possible. For the Hadoop/Spark client, I only want to use a simple way such as account and password for authentication. For example, I can write the account password in the configuration file in core-site.xml and yarn-site.xml to verify if I have data permissions and queue usage permissions.

Comment: It must be Kerberos. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html